# Exception: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

I have a sandbox for exploring newly added functions in Spring Cloud Stream, but I've faced a problem with using Function and Supplier in one Spring Cloud Stream application.

In code I used examples described in [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-reference).

Firstly I added to project `Function<String, String>` with corresponding `spring.cloud.stream.bindings` and `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` properties in `application.yml`. Everything is working fine, I post message to `my-fun-in` Kafka topic, application execute function and send result to `my-fun-out` topic.

Then I added `Supplier<Flux<String>>` to the same project with corresponding `spring.cloud.stream.bindings` and updated `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` value to `fun;sup`. And here weird things start to happen. When I try to start application I receive the following error:

```
2020-01-15 01:45:16.608 ERROR 10128 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.sup-out-0'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[20], headers={contentType=application/json, id=89301e00-b285-56e0-cb4d-8133555c8905, timestamp=1579045516603}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[20], headers={contentType=application/json, id=89301e00-b285-56e0-cb4d-8133555c8905, timestamp=1579045516603}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.doSend(AbstractMessageRouter.java:206)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:188)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.onNext(AbstractMessageHandler.java:219)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.onNext(AbstractMessageHandler.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.ReactiveStreamsConsumer$DelegatingSubscriber.hookOnNext(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.java:165)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.ReactiveStreamsConsumer$DelegatingSubscriber.hookOnNext(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.java:148)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BaseSubscriber.onNext(BaseSubscriber.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:123)
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:426)
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.onNext(EmitterProcessor.java:268)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:793)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.next(FluxCreate.java:718)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink.next(FluxCreate.java:153)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.doSend(FluxMessageChannel.java:63)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.lambda$subscribeTo$2(FluxMessageChannel.java:83)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:189)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:398)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:484)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[20], headers={contentType=application/json, id=89301e00-b285-56e0-cb4d-8133555c8905, timestamp=1579045516603}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    ... 34 more
```

After it I've tried several thing:

1. Reverted `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` to `fun` (disable `sup` bean binding to the external destination). Application started, function worked, supplier didn't work. Everything as expected.
2. Changed `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` to `sup` (disable `fun` bean binding to the external destination). Application started, function didn't work, supplier worked (produced message to `my-sup-out` topic every second). Everything as expected as well.
3. Updated `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` value to `fun;sup`. Application didn't start, got same MessageDeliveryException.
4. Swapped `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` value to `sup;fun`. Application **started**, supplier worked, **but function didn't work** (didn't send messages to `my-fun-out` topic).

The last one confused me even more than error) So now I need someone's help to sort thing out.

**Did I miss something in cofiguration? Why changing beans order separated by `;` in `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` leads to different results?**

Full project is uploaded to [GitHub](https://github.com/al3xka1n3/spring-cloud-stream-issue-01) and added below:

*StreamApplication.java:*

```
package com.kaine;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StreamApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StreamApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> fun() {
        return value -> value.toUpperCase();
    }

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<String>> sup() {
        return () -> Flux.from(emitter -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    emitter.onNext("Hello from Supplier!");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*application.yml*

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: fun;sup
      bindings:
        fun-in-0:
          destination: my-fun-in
        fun-out-0:
          destination: my-fun-out
        sup-out-0:
          destination: my-sup-out
```

*build.gradle.kts:*

```
plugins {
    java
}

group = "com.kaine"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
        implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.SR1"))
        implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka")

        implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.2.RELEASE"))
}

configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is a problem with our documentation as I believe we provide a bad example of the reactive Supplier for his case. The issue is that your Supplier is in an infinite blocking loop. It basically never returns. 
So please change it to something like:

```
@Bean
public Supplier<Flux<String>> sup() {
    return () -> Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(new Supplier<String>() {

        @Override
        public String get() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return "Hello from Supplier";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }

    })).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()).share();
}
```

Comment: Oleg, I've tried your code snippet and it's really solve my problem. Thank you for advice)
P.S. Small note: get method requires `return` after `try`/`catch`, otherwise compiler will yell about "missing return statement"

Comment: @Oleg Can you just explain why the code in the qestion is blocking? Thx